# Operación no permitida como usuario Root

Tags: centos

Tengo un disco particionado  /dev/sda2  (es un disco secundario con datos de windows)
El sistema operativo esta en otro disco con Centos 8

En el archivo fstab, tengo lo siguiente para mapear dicha particion con en una carpeta en el escritorio del usuario del sistema

/dev/disk/by-uuid/8C36B88236B86F38 /home/user01/Escritorio/Datos auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

La particion, aparece correctamente en el escritorio (se mapea correctamente), pero con el usuario "User01" no puedo escribir en dicha particion.

intente cambiar el usuario de la carpeta /home/user01/Escritorio/Datos desde el usuario root

[root@fco Escritorio]# chown -R user01:user01 Datos

pero me sale el mensaje de error

chown: cambiando el propietario de 'Desa': Operación no permitida

la carpeta desa esta vacia, y sigue teniendo el propietrario root,

ls -ltra
drwxrwxrwx   1 root    root     8192 ene  9 21:01 Datos

en algunos lugares he leido que puede ser que la particion este montada como solo de lectura, pero en el fstab no aparece una indicacion de esto.

el proceso de montaje, lo hice a traves de la utilidad de administracion de discos de centos 8 (grafico) y tampoco tiene ninguna opcion de montar como solo lectura.

Alguna idea de porque no se pueda cambiar el propietario a la carpeta?

Comment: Intenta con `chown user01:user01 Datos`, si es posible inténtalo sin que la partición esté montada.

Comment: te agradezco el comentario benjamin, el prpoblema era que en el archivo /etc/fstab no estab indicando que la particin era de lectura/escritura. basto con cambiar por /dev/disk/by-uuid/8C36B88236B86F38 /home/user01/Escritorio/Datos ntfs rw,auto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0 y cin eso la particion ya tenia permisos de escritura, y no se hacia necesario cambiar su ownwer.